# How to check if two passengers have same name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, compare

I have 2 input boxes for first name and last name of passengers travelling.
There could be maximum 9 number of passengers.
It is not allowed to have two passengers with same name(first and last combined)
How can I check if none of the passenger have same names(first and last name combined)

```
<input type="text" name="adultFirstName1" id="adultFirstName1" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" style="width:100%; padding:5px;">
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I am not using a database to store the passenger names and the passengers are all entered on the same page.

Comment: What if two passengers *do* have the same name...!?! I mean, in real life!?

Comment: hat have you tried so far?

Comment: @deceze That's not allowed by the API.. Passengers may have to enter initials of one of the passengers..

Comment: @PrerakSola Yes but I'm actually not getting the way how to do it.. I was thinking of taking all the first names in one array and last names in other then I was messed up on comparing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var name=[];    
var sameName=false;
for(var i=1;i<=<%=detailsModel.getNumberOfAdult()%>;i++)
 {
var fullName = document.getElementById("adultFirstName"+i).value+" "+document.getElementById("adultLastName"+i).value
name.push(fullName);
}
for(var i=1;i<=<%=detailsModel.getNumberOfChild()%>;i++)
{
var fullName = document.getElementById("childFirstName"+i).value+" "+document.getElementById("childLastName"+i).value
name.push(fullName);

}
for(var i=1;i<=<%=detailsModel.getNumberOfInfant()%>;i++)
{
var fullName = document.getElementById("infantFirstName"+i).value+" "+document.getElementById("infantLastName"+i).value
name.push(fullName);
}
for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++)
{
for(var j=i+1;j<name.length;j++)
    {
    if(name[i]==name[j])
    {
        var sameName=true
        valid= false;
    }

  }
}
if(sameName==true)
    {
    $('#sameNameError').html('2 Passengers Cannot Have Same Name');
    }
else
    {
    $('#sameNameError').html('');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a verification javascript function , but first u need to have specific names for all input boxes . 
U can try something like this :

```
<input type="text" name="adultFirstName1" id="adultFirstName1" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" style="width:100%; padding:5px;" OnClick="Verify();">
.
.
.
<input type="text" name="adultFirstName10" id="adultFirstName10" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" style="width:100%; padding:5px;" OnClick="Verify(id);">
```

then you'll need to verify at every change of value of a boxe .

Answer (score -1):

Are there 2 input boxes for each passenger? If so, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        if($("#adultFirstName1").val() == $("#adultFirstName2").val() 
            && $("#adultLastName1").val() == $("#adultLastName2").val()) {

            //Names are the same

        }
    });
});
```

Or are you needing to check against the names of other passengers already in a database somewhere?

Comment: Thanks :), but that will only compare 2 passengers. What if there are 9 passengers.
Probably pushing them in array and then comparing each of them would work.. I'm working on it.. I'll post if I do that.. Already got enough negative votes.. :(

Comment: I'll give you an upvote. Try editing your question to expand a little more. Are you using a database? Do you enter all passengers on the same page? You'll get it, don't worry!

Comment: No I'm not using database. yes, passengers are entered on the same page.
And I answered it below.
Thank You